# What statistical test would I use with 2 groups and a control to show significant difference?

Tags: r, anova, t-test

Question I would like to answer: To encourage more referrals, the product team is running an experiment on the iOS app, called “ios_referral_experiment”, that tests adding new links to the referral invite page. The experiment has 3 groups: the “control” group has no new link; the “tab_only” group has a new navigation tab that links to the page; and the “tab_settings” group has both a new navigation tab and a new link in the settings. What are the results from this experiment and what would you  recommend?

I have a table that looks  like so:

```
event_type                          test_group                         Total_Impressions
referrer_page_invite_action          control                            1892        
referrer_page_invite_action          tab_only                           4009        
referrer_page_invite_action          tab_settings                       2995        
referrer_page_viewed                 control                            25382       
referrer_page_viewed                 tab_only                           63372       
referrer_page_viewed                 tab_settings                       44473
```

My goal is to determine if the **split_test_group** have significant differences on *total impression* when compared to control. I would do two seperate tests for each **event_type** variables.

I was thinking a simple t-test but was unsure and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But what happened to the counts $25383, 63372, 44473$ in your original data table. It is not possible to compare Total Impression counts with each other without knowing the total number of subjects on each of the rows of your table. (Are the three groups now of the same size? If so, what size?)

Comment: I did not mean to delete that...sorry. Updated. Would your answer still follow given the updated info?

Comment: Yes, but instead of saying 'independent', now I'd re-phrase to say that the proportions of impressions in the three groups are not the same.

Comment: Okay - so the rows of your TBL would be the 'event_type' and the columns would be the 3 groups im measuring against.

Answer (score 1):

Comment:

You don't explain your experiment or its goals, and the labels
in your data table are cryptic. However, it looks as if you may have
a $2\times 3$ contingency table `TBL` of counts, with $142\,124$
subjects altogether.

```
TBL = rbind(c(1892,4009,2995),c(25383,63372,44473)); TBL
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  1892  4009  2995
[2,] 25383 63372 44473
sum(TBL)
[1] 142124
```

If this accurately describes your data, then a chi-squared test
rejects the null hypothesis that row and column categories are
independent, with P-value near $0.$

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 32.542, df = 2, p-value = 8.583e-08
```

Pearson residuals in the first two cells of the first row show
large absolute values, indicating that the largest discrepancies,
between the *observed counts* in `TBL` and the six *expected counts*
(computed on the assumption that the null hypothesis is true),
are in these two cells of the table. The sum of squares of these
six residuals is the test statistic $32.542.$

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)$res
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  4.471824 -3.211960  0.4370811
[2,] -1.155538  0.829984 -0.1129436
```

*Note:* If this is not a correct interpretation, please edit your Question
for clarity. [As you question stands, I see no role for a t test.]

---

**Addendum:**  Here is basically the same chi-squared test as above
but organized to focus on three proportions (which are apparently not all the same).

```
Inv=c(1892,4009,2995)
View = c(25383,63372,44473)
Tot = Inv + View

        3-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  Inv out of Tot
X-squared = 32.542, df = 2, p-value = 8.583e-08
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2     prop 3 
0.06936755 0.05949748 0.06309514
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I added more context and simplified the data table. The goal is come up with a  method that can accurately determine which 'test_group' has the best influence on more 'referrals'. The table I posted is the sum of each group (does not include individual users/time info).